# PowerEdge T430 - BSOD after OS (Server 2008 R2) applied

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, dell-poweredge, bsod

I am trying to verify the PowerEdge T430 for deployment to our customers through MDT. I have setup the drivers in MDT appropriately for the model by downloading the drivers from Dell.com.

When we run our server-build sequence in MDT on the T430, everything works as it should until the OS is applied and the system is rebooted.

Windows Server 2008 R2 brings up the loading (green progress bar) screen and it takes about ~30 seconds to BSOD. The BSOD disappears immediately and the system reboots.

I boot into a WinPE enviroment and check the C:\windows and there is no "Minidump" folder and there are no relevant logs in C:\Windows\Panther.

Is there something I can set in the PowerEdge BIOS to stop the BSOD from disappearing? Something I can set in the Server 2008 R2 image (registry)? How can I troubleshoot this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to give a look at this article.

https://www.technibble.com/how-to-disable-automatic-restart-for-bsod-if-you-are-unable-to-get-into-windows/

Comment: F8! God, it's amazing what you forget when you never use it.